# Why is my edit function adding instead of editing the member?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, edit

I'm trying to build a team roster for my class. I got it to where the code won't produce any errors, but when I edit a member, it adds a member to the dictionary instead of editing the member I told it to.

For the assignment we have to have a class(which I don't completely understand the point of yet), and I had written a code previously when we were just adding names where I was able to get a functioning code using mainly just a while loop, but I had gotten points removed because I didn't have def statements.

```
class nameClass:
    name = ""
    phoneNumber = ""
    jerseyNumber = ""

    def __int__(self, name, phoneNumber, jerseyNumber):
        self.name = name
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        self.jerseyNumber = jerseyNumber

    def setname(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def setphoneNumber(self, phoneNumber):
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
    def setjerseyNumber(self, jerseyNumber):
        self.jerseyNumber = jerseyNumber

    def getname(self):
        return self.name
    def getphoneNumber(self):
        return self.phoneNumber
    def getjerseyNumber(self):
        return self.jerseyNumber
    def displayData(self):
        print(" ")
        print("Player information: ")
        print("-------------------------")
        print("Name: ", self.name)
        print("Phone number: ", self.phoneNumber)
        print("Jersey number: ", self.jerseyNumber)

def displayMenu():
    print("=========Main Menu=========")
    print("1. Display Roster.")
    print("2. Add Member.")
    print("3. Remove Member.")
    print("4. Edit Member.")
    print("9. Exit Program.")
    print(" ")
    return int(input("Selection > "))

def printMembers(members):
    if menuSelection == 1:
        print("Team Roster:")
        for x in members.keys():
            print("Name: ", x, "\tPhone Number: ", x, "\tJersey Number: ", members[x])
        print()

def addMember(members):
    if menuSelection == 2:
        newName = input("Enter new member's name: ")
        newphoneNumber = int(input("Enter member's phone number: "))
        newjerseyNumber = int(input("Enter member's jersey number: "))
        members[newName] = (newName, newphoneNumber, newjerseyNumber)
    return members

def removeMember(members):
    if menuSelection == 3:
        name = input("Enter the member's name you would like to remove: ")
        if name in members:
            del members[name]
        else:
            print("Member: ", name, "not found.")
    return members

def editMember(members):
    if menuSelection == 4:
        oldName = input("Enter the name of the member you would like to edit: ")
        if oldName in members:
            newName = input("Enter the member's new name: ")
            newphoneNumber = int(input("Member's new phone number: "))
            newjerseyNumber = int(input("Member's new jersey number: "))
            members[newName] = (newName, newphoneNumber, newjerseyNumber)
        else:
            print("No such member in memory.")
    return members

print("Welome to the Team Manager")
members = {}
menuSelection = displayMenu()

while menuSelection != 9:
    if menuSelection == 1:
        printMembers(members)
    elif menuSelection == 2:
        members = addMember(members)
    elif menuSelection == 3:
        members = removeMember(members)
    elif menuSelection == 4:
        members = editMember(members)
    menuSelection = displayMenu()
print("Exiting Program...")
```

Like I said, everything seems to work just fine when it's run except you realize when you print the roster, it adds a new member instead of editing like you told it to.

Comment: Why do you define `nameClass` but never use it?

Comment: I'm in my 5th week of my first programming class ever. I'm mainly going off of the example codes given. I've tried reading about class statements, but I don't understand why one was in the example for this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Change your printMembers():

```
def printMembers(members):
    if menuSelection == 1:
        print("Team Roster:")
        for key, value in members.items():
            print("Name: ", key, "\tPhone Number: ", value[1], "\tJersey Number: ", value[2])
        print()
```

Try it.

Comment: For some reason my output looks like this. The phone number and jersery number don't even end up under the correct label: Unfortunately neither of the suggestions worked. I feel like a class statement was added in for a reason on the example code, but I don't know how to use it properly. Maybe that could be why the code isn't working? =========Main Menu=========
1. Display Roster.
2. Add Member.
3. Remove Member.
4. Edit Member.
9. Exit Program.
 
Selection > 1
Team Roster:
Name:  josh  Phone Number:  josh  Jersey Number:  ('josh', 1234, 23)

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not delete the old member. The line `members[newName] = (newName, newphoneNumber, newjerseyNumber)` in the edit function simply add the new member with a new key. Unless you type the same name (used as key), in that case will be overwritten.

The same behaviour happens if you try to add a new member which has the same name of a member already in your dict. It will overwrite the previous one, since dictionary keys must be unique, and you do not check the presence of an identical name in the dictionary.

The shortest way to fix the edit mode in your code is to add:

```
del members[oldName]
```

in your `editMember` function, inside the `if oldName in members` statement. So you will delete the *old* dictionary entry and replace it with a new one.

In general, I suggest you to use a numeric id automatically generated by the code as key, instead of the name. This will make easier to edit and add new members, and members with the same name are allowed.
A class (which by the way you have defined but never used, so it's really pointless to have it) should help you in doing this easily.